# AppDomainUnloadedException when unit-testing a WinForms form with an animated gif

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, unit-testing, animation

Some of our integration tests (implemented as Visual Studio Unit Tests) show WinForms forms. For some of them, we happen to get the following message in the test output window:

```
------ Run test started ------
System.AppDomainUnloadedException: Attempted to access an unloaded AppDomain. This can happen if the test(s) started a thread but did not stop it. Make sure that all the threads started by the test(s) are stopped before completion.
========== Run test finished: 1 run (0:00:00,1699987) ==========
```

I narrowed it down to forms which include animated gifs in a PictureBox and managed to create an MCVE:

```vb
<TestMethod()>
Public Sub AppDomainException()
    Using f As New Testform()
        f.Show()
        f.Close()
    End Using
End Sub

Public Class Testform
    Inherits Form

    Private Const Gif = "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"
    Private Const AnimatedGif = "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"

    Private pib As PictureBox

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()

        pib = New PictureBox()

        ' Change AnimagedGif to Gif and the problem disappears
        Using ms As New MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(AnimatedGif))
            pib.Image = New Bitmap(ms)
        End Using

        Me.Controls.Add(pib)
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(disposing As Boolean)
        If disposing Then
            pib.Dispose()
        End If
        MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Apparently, the PictureBox starts some kind of background thread to animate the gif and does not properly stop it when it is disposed. Is there a way to force it to do so or is this a bug in the PictureBox control?

Comment: Note: I tagged this with both C# and VB.NET, since this is a problem of the WinForms framework, not of the language. The example just happens to be in VB, since I was working on a VB project while discovering this. I still want to invite the C# crowd to have a look at this (and I can translate my example, of course, if need be).

Comment: There is no mechanism to get that thread to terminate.  This can't possibly be a surprise.

Comment: @HansPassant: Why isn't that surprising? Isn't the (implied) contract that disposing a component cleans up all resources, including (if required) worker threads?

Comment: Downvoter: Feedback to improve the question is appreciated.